# Making 1 single JButton change panel background

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

Quick question how would you make 1 `JButton` change the color of the panel when clicked and displays what color it is I've done some tutorials having 3 `JButtons` color change when a different button is clicked  but how you make just one `JButton` change the panel color for example yellow, green, and red.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

   public class ChangeButtonColor{
   JButton button;
   public static void main(String[] args){
   ChangeButtonColor cl = new ChangeButtonColor();
  }

   public ChangeButtonColor(){
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Change JButton Color");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      button = new JButton();
      button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
      frame.add(button);
      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

  public class MyAction implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


   }
 }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine what color is the color to be set?

Comment: Thats the thing i wanted to make it depending on the number of clicks i guess 1 click= red 2 clicks= green, etc.

Comment: NVM lol maybe i could do for example when the button is clicked (if panel color is red print out red , else if panel is green print out green) would that be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "maybe i could do for example when the button is clicked (if panel color is red print out red , else if panel is green print out green) would that be good"

You can just check `if (panel.getBackground() == Color.RED)`, for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorClick {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
            {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };
        JButton button = new JButton("Change Color");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (panel.getBackground() == Color.RED) {
                    System.out.println("RED");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (panel.getBackground() == Color.GREEN) {
                    System.out.println("GREEN");
                    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh cool thanks and one more question if i wanted to addd 2 more colors all i have to use is else if right ??

Comment: Thanks alot and if i wanted to change the text inside the button all i use us label.setText(blahblh); right

Comment: button.setText, but yeah